# Can UserManager.GetUserAsync(User) return null in a class with Authorize attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.net core 2.0 MVC with Individual User Account enabled. The automatically-generated `ManageController` class is attributed by `[Authorize]`.

I find there are some action methods with the following code snippet.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
if (user == null)
{
 throw new ApplicationException($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
}
```

## Question

In my mental model, being authorized guarantees being a registered user. So such a null checking in authorized classes seems to be unnecessary. I want to know whether or not  `UserManager.GetUserAsync(User)` can return `null` in a class with `Authorize` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know whether or not UserManager.GetUserAsync(User) can return null in a class with Authorize attribute?

It can, if the user entry was removed from the database after the user logged in (by default, cookies are validated after [30 minutes](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Identity/SecurityStampValidatorOptions.cs#L20) so they can still be "valid" even after the corresponding user was removed from the database).